# How can I notify my activity that the alarm manager has launched its pending intent?

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am implementing a feature in my application that allows users to set reminders at a specified time.

In my reminder activity I have a TimePicker, two buttons and a text view.
One button is to set a reminder to the time displayed on the TimePicker and the other is to cancel an already set reminder. When a user sets a reminder the time at which it is set is displayed in the text view and when it is cancelled the text view is cleared.

I am using AlarmManager and PendingIntent to trigger my NotificationService at the user-specified time but I cant figure out a way to indicate to my reminder activity that the notification has been shown to then remove the reminder time from the text view.

In short... when my notification is shown I want my text view to be empty.

Comment: I realise that it wouldn't be at all efficient but could I write a 'notified' boolean to SharedPreference in the NotificationService and then read getSharedPreference value in my reminder activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use BroadcastReceiver to receive Alarm, or if you want to receive Alarm in NotificationService only, then you can broadcast that from NotificationService and listen that through BroadcastReceiver registered in your reminder activity.

Checkout BroadcastReceiver tutorials:

With AlarmManager
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

With Activity
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Starting-Background-Services#communicating-from-a-service-to-an-application